# Что означает @ в названиях npm пакетов?

Tags: npm

Я использую `babel`.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    ...
  },
```

Что означает `@` в названиях пакетов?

Какая разница при установки пакета с `@`  и без `@`?

Как обновлять такие пакеты?

Потому что библиотека `chai` установлена последней версии (хотя я ее ставил очень давно), а `babel` есть версия `7.5.5`, но она не устанавливается.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope